# filling drop down menu by json file in dat.gui

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, dat.gui

I am making a drop down menu using javascript 
here is the json file

```
{
 "bg1":"assets/bg/people_bg.jpg",
 "bg2":"assets/bg/people_bg.jpg"
}
```

I am just trying to put name as bg1 and bg2 to bg(n) to drop down and so user can select any background.Here is my code for dat.gui();

```
{
controller = new function() {
this.bg = '';
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
f1 = gui.addFolder('Sphere');
f1.add( controller, 'bg', displayingNameOfBackground).onChange(function() {
    //if change using their path to change background
            );
```

Comment: Your json is not valid. Check it with this [validator](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Corrected..How can i now make drop down menu?

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want as result, but as an option, you can do it like this:

```js
var json = {
  "background": {
    "bg1": "assets/bg/people_bg1.jpg",
    "bg2": "assets/bg/people_bg2.jpg"
  }
};

var gui = new dat.GUI();
f1 = gui.addFolder('Sphere');
f1.add(json, "background", json.background).onChange(function(value) {
  alert(value) // do the stuff to change background
});
f1.open();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```